# Problems getting local notification sound in foreground application

Tags: ios

I need to play a sound at a certain time (a wake up alarm) in a foreground app. I have it working so it plays if in the background. I have yet to find a working code example that will play a sound in the foreground app. They all seem to produce compiler errors in XCode 8.2.1 and iOS10.2

Can anyone point me to some code that successfully does this? Getting it exactly right seems to be the problem, so seeing some working code would be a big help. Or is there some issue I don't know about?

Comment: How do we know what you don't know about? _You_ show _your_ code, please. In particular, prove that your app is receiving the notification when you are in the foreground. This depends upon your provision of a UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. Show how you are doing that.

Comment: I suppose that is the core of my problem. I am finding the explanations of how to provide a UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate unclear as to how/where to do this. Apple says you must do this early, and I have tried doing so in AppDelegate, which I presume should be my delegate for this also. I use this code:   extension NotificationManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void){ ...  }

Comment: Well, I can't see the whole thing but it sounds good in theory. Here's me setting it up in the app delegate: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch13p630localNotification/ch26p899localNotification/AppDelegate.swift And here's the delegate, MyUserNotificationHelper: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch13p630localNotification/ch26p899localNotification/ViewController.swift Hope that helps some; the example is downloadable.

Comment: If this solves this problem, I'll buy your book (if it's available in PDF form or iBook, I'm on the road and can't get paper books) for sure! Is it?

Comment: Hitting an XCode error with your code: if let textresponse = response as? UNTextInputNotificationResponse {
            let text = textresponse.userText
            print("user text was \(text)")
        }
gets a 'computed property must have an explicit type' red error. Also  completionHandler() has an 'Expected declaration' error